# Why is htaccess returning full path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying the following in htaccess and everything works except one detail: It posts the whole /var/www/project path instead of just giving me what I think I am telling it to give me.

When I type `dev.mysite.com/folder`

it correctly gives me `http://dev.mysite.com/index.php?path=folder`, as expected.

---

---

However, in the other case, I am expecting this: `http://dev.mysite.com/index.php?path=main.php&u=1079`

but instead it gives me `http://dev.mysite.com/index.php?path=var/www/dev.mysite.com/main.php&u=1079`

(example url: 1079.dev.mysite.com (where 1079 is a user profile))

```
RewriteEngine On
# force non-www domain
RewriteBase /

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.php?u=%1

# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/].*[^\?])
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.mysite.com/index.php?path=%1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Now, I wonder:

1) **What am I doing wrong?**

2) **Is what I want even possible?**

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: What happens when you enter URL as: `http://1079.dev.mysite.com/main.php&u=1079` in browser?

Comment: It returned `http://dev.mysite.com/index.php?path=main.php&u=1079&u=1079`

Comment: I tried switching main.php&%1 but that still returns the whole var/www thing

Comment: Is `/main.php` a real file?

Comment: It is, so i renamed it to test, still the same result.

Comment: If `main.php` is a valid file then last rule shouldn't even fire due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: Maybe it fires because I changed main.php&u=%1 so its looking for a file named main.php&u=%1 instead? I might have a workable solution now though thanks to that &u=%1 instead of using a ?

Comment: But you have `/main.php?u=%1` not `/main.php&u=%1`

Comment: There is a comment which suggested main.php&u=1079  - I tried it, it failed, but gave me an idea - putting it like that in the htaccess file! So I adapted the regex below to that string and it works. I try things while waiting instead of waiting for someone to give me an out of the box answer :)

You left an idea inspiring comment, much thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much thanks to anubhava for his help in the comments =) as it inspired the solution.

I switched the first rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.php&u=%1
```

Then the last condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)$
```